# Google Sheets Auto Filter

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make an automated google sheet which will filter pending IDs on column P every 5 minutes to avoid reediting the entry.

So I tried to record a macro and put a trigger on it but the trigger didn't work. I am having an error of "setColumnFilterCriteria' of null at UntitledMacro(macros:7:43)"

The editors of the said file is about 10 people with editor restriction but are retricted on other columns. Hope you can help. Thanks in advance

Below were the codes of the macro recorder:

```
function UntitledMacro() {
    var spreadsheet = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.Getrange('P1').activate(); varcriteria=SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['Completed', 'Other']).build(); spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(16, criteria) ;
};
```

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Is there already a filter in your sheet? Also, a space is missed in`varcriteria`

Comment: Yes, there is. Sorry for the spaces coz I typed it manually.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of errors/issues and your expected output/behavior? Also, try formatting your code by blocking it properly for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You encountered such error because your current active sheet doesn't have an existing filter. If there is no current filter in the sheet, [getFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getfilter) will return `null`. Hence [setColumnFilterCriteria()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria) don't exist.

As a workaround, you can include an `if condition` to check if the current sheet doesn't have any filter yet. Then create a new filter.

### Sample Code:

```
function UntitledMacro() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    Logger.log(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter());
    spreadsheet.getRange('P1').activate();
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['Completed', 'Other']).build(); 
    var filter = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter();

    if(filter){
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(16, criteria);
    }else{
      //There is currently no filter in the selected sheet
      //Create new filter in Cell P1
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('P1:P').createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(16, criteria);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update accordingly

Comment: I updated the answer. Changed range from `getRange('P1)` to `getRange('P1:P')`.